# Which font extensions do you really use?

Tags: css, sass

I see in many projects that people use all the extensions of fonts like .TTF, .WOFF, .WOFF2. However this causes many files to a single source, imagine if I have several sources of various types?

I'm only using .WOFF2 but I've noticed that on INTERNET EXPLORER and on TV's browsers like LG, the source does not work.

Comment: You could load different CSS files, (with different font extensions), based on the browser.

Comment: You should use different font formats for each font face you define. You can use some online service to generate them though, it's actually easier than it sounds. Google "webfont generator" and you'll find a lot of resources to upload one format and the service just gives you the other formats and the css.

Answer (score 1):

I would use **woff2** and **woff** to include older browsers:

```
Chrome  Safari  Firefox Opera   IE  Android iOS
5+      5.1+    3.6+    11.50+  9+  4.4+    5.1+
```

**Tip!** When creating @font-face rules – use the same FontFamilyName for all weights. 
It makes it a lot easier to handle variations in your CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontFamilyName';
  src:  url('../fonts/FontFileName.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/FontFileName.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontFamilyName';
  src:  url('../fonts/FontFileName-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/FontFileName-Bold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Make sure you add a fallback (font stack) to support browsers that either does not support woff or does not support web fonts at all (I'm not sure LG does)

```
h1 { font: 700 2rem 'FontFamilyName', sans-serif; }
p  { font: 400 1rem 'FontFamilyName', sans-serif; }
strong { font-weight: 700; }
```

Comment: For me not to need to enter all kinds of font extensions, which one would you recommend to span all browsers and devices?

Comment: I wouldn't it would be bad advice. It's about how fast your page loads. TTF has the widest support but costs more to load than WOFF and WOFF2 (the lightest). By providing multiple options the browser picks the fastest. If you don't care about load speed then use WOFF